# Print VBA dictionary into text file

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, text

Is there a way to print a dictionary into a text?  I have a dictionary with 100+ keys and would like to print it into a tab delimited text file if possible.  This seems so simple but I cannot figure it out--i.e. I am new VBA user.

```
'Defining text file variable
Dim FilePath As String

'Text file path
 FilePath = path & "\OrderStatus.txt"

'Open the text file
Open FilePath For Output As #1
'OrderStatus is the dictionary
Write #1, OrderStatus

Close #1
```

Comment: What is your 'dictionary' - a worksheet? You want to export data to a tab delimited text file? Did you consider Excel SaveAs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'Defining text file variable
Dim FilePath As String

'Text file path
 FilePath = path & "\OrderStatus.txt"

Dim key As Variant
'Open the text file
Open FilePath For Output As #1
With OrderStatus
    For Each key In .keys
        Write #1, key & “,” & .Item(key)
    Next
End With
Close #1
```

Comment: @Koda,  did this solution not work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
Sub Webster()
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    dict.Add "winken", 1
    dict.Add "blinken", 2
    dict.Add "nod", 3

    Close #1
    Open "C:\TestFolder\TestFile.txt" For Output As #1

    For Each ky In dict.keys
        Print #1, ky & " " & dict(ky)
    Next ky

    Close #1
End Sub
```

[image]

*(You can replace the space with a tab if you prefer.)*

Comment: just FYI, I had to do something similar to this recently with hundreds of thousands of rows and it's *significantly* quicker to fill a variant with each line and print to the output just once, i.e. `Print #1, Join(v, vbCrLf)`.

Comment: @CallumDA  ..............that is a super good idea!